# Unable to translate click coordinates to picturebox

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a `PictureBox` with some graphics drawn, able to zoom by mousewheel. To keep the graphics at the (approximately) same position, not to have to move each time after zooming, I translate the graphics after each zoom. Here is my zooming code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
    float _step = 1.0f;
    if (todo == "zoom out")
    {
        float step = 0;
        if (CurrentRate >= 0.60f) step = 0.05f;
        else if (CurrentRate >= 0.40f && CurrentRate < 0.60f) step = 0.025f;
        else if (CurrentRate >= 0.05f && CurrentRate < 0.40f) step = 0.0125f;
        CurrentRate -= step; // current rate is 1.0 on startup
        _step = step;
        //pictureBox1.Location = new Point((int)(pictureBox1.Location.X + step * 1500), (int)(pictureBox1.Location.Y + step * 1500));
        translateX += step * 10500; //achieved these numbers after few dozens of tries, it actually keeps the graphics at the same position..
        translateY += step * 8500;
        todo = null;
    }
    else if (todo == "zoom in")
    {
        float step = 0;
        if (CurrentRate >= 1.80f && CurrentRate <= 1.95f) step = 0.0125f;
        else if (CurrentRate >= 0.80f && CurrentRate < 1.80f) step = 0.025f;
        else if (CurrentRate >= 0.03f && CurrentRate < 0.80f) step = 0.05f;
        CurrentRate += step;
        _step = step;
        translateX -= step * 10500;
        translateY -= step * 8500;
        //pictureBox1.Location = new Point((int)(pictureBox1.Location.X - step * 1500), (int)(pictureBox1.Location.Y - step * 1500));
        todo = null;
    }

    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(translateX, translateY); //move it to keep same position
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(CurrentRate, CurrentRate); //rescale according to the zoom
   //the drawing itself (of everything, also the things mentioned below)
```

Now, what I am trying to do. The user clicks the picturebox, a small rectangle should be drawn at the click position. When he clicks again, another rectangle is drawn, and the rectangles are connected by a line. And on and on to lets say 50 connected rectangles.

Now, the rectangles connect correctly, but everything is drawn with a horrible offset. I believe this is caused by the translation. So I tried to translate the click coordinates as well:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("e.Location: " + e.Location.ToString() + "to client e.location: " + PointToClient(e.Location).ToString() +  "cursor position: " + Cursor.Position.ToString() + "to client cursor position:" + PointToClient(Cursor.Position).ToString() + "/nto screen cursor position: " + PointToScreen(Cursor.Position).ToString());
        if (trackDrawing)
        {
            Point[] rectanglePos = new Point[1];
            rectanglePos[0] = new Point(e.Location.X + (int)(translateX), e.Location.Y + (int)translateY);
            drawBuffer.Add(rectanglePos);
            drawBuffertype.Add("DRAWTRACKRECTANGLE");
            if (trackDrawingBuffer.Count > 0)
            {
                Point[] linePos = new Point[2];
                linePos[0] = trackDrawingBuffer[trackDrawingBuffer.Count - 1];
                linePos[1] = new Point(e.Location.X + (int)translateX, e.Location.Y + (int)translateY); ;
                drawBuffer.Add(linePos);
                drawBuffertype.Add("DRAWTRACKLINE");
            }
            trackDrawingBuffer.Add(new Point(e.Location.X + (int)translateX, e.Location.Y + (int)translateY));
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
 //some more unrelated code
```

But that doesn't work. I have tried also without the translates here at the MouseDown event, but still it draws with offset. I am not quite sure how to describe the behavior properly, so I have done a short vid (about 30s) to explain the offset..
[The video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bmLhwJKN_I)

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

**

### EDIT

**

Now, after edits done according to the answers, my code looks this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (trackDrawing)
        {
            Matrix m = transform.Clone();
            m.Invert();
            Point[] rectanglePos = new Point[1];
            rectanglePos[0] = new Point(e.Location.X - 3, e.Location.Y - 3);
            m.TransformPoints(rectanglePos);
            drawBuffer.Add(rectanglePos);
            drawBuffertype.Add("DRAWTRACKRECTANGLE");
            if (trackDrawingBuffer.Count > 0)
            {
                Point[] linePos = new Point[2];
                linePos[0] = trackDrawingBuffer[trackDrawingBuffer.Count - 1];
                linePos[1] = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y );
                m.TransformPoints(linePos);
                drawBuffer.Add(linePos);
                drawBuffertype.Add("DRAWTRACKLINE");
            }
            trackDrawingBuffer.Add(rectanglePos[0]);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Now, here the translating part, including the code where I get the matrix offset

```
        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
        transform.Translate(-translateX, -translateY);
        float _step = 1.0f;
        if (todo == "zoom out")
        {
            float step = 0;
            if (CurrentRate >= 0.60f) step = 0.05f;
            else if (CurrentRate >= 0.40f && CurrentRate < 0.60f) step = 0.025f;
            else if (CurrentRate >= 0.05f && CurrentRate < 0.40f) step = 0.0125f;
            CurrentRate -= step;
            _step = step;
            translateX += step * 10500;
            translateY += step * 8500;
            todo = null;
        }
        else if (todo == "zoom in")
        {
            float step = 0;
            if (CurrentRate >= 1.80f && CurrentRate <= 1.95f) step = 0.0125f;
            else if (CurrentRate >= 0.80f && CurrentRate < 1.80f) step = 0.025f;
            else if (CurrentRate >= 0.03f && CurrentRate < 0.80f) step = 0.05f;
            CurrentRate += step;
            _step = step;
            //pictureBox1.Scale((1f + step), (1f + step));
            translateX -= step * 10500;
            translateY -= step * 8500;
            todo = null;
        }

        transform.Translate(translateX, translateY); // transform is the Matrix

        e.Graphics.Transform = transform;
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(CurrentRate, CurrentRate);
```

and here the drawing itself:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < drawBuffer.Count; i++)
        {
        //...
else if (drawBuffertype[i].ToUpper().Contains("DRAWTRACKRECTANGLE"))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), drawBuffer[i][0].X, drawBuffer[i][0].Y, 6, 6);
                }
                else if (drawBuffertype[i].ToUpper().Contains("DRAWTRACKLINE"))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.OrangeRed, 2), drawBuffer[i][0], drawBuffer[i][1]);
                }
```

And still drawing like in the first part of video. I just have to be missing something really basic here...

Comment: You'll want to use the Matrix class here to keep track of your translates and scales.  You can directly assign it to Graphics.Transform before you paint.  Mapping a mouse position back is now very simple, use Matrix.Invert() and Matrix.TransformPoints()

Comment: Thank you Hans, I have just tried this after reading the last answer, but still drawing with the top-left offset.. Hold on a second, will add some more code, I just have to be missing something here

Comment: Okay, I don't quite understand this, but after I switched from e.Graphics.Scale to the Matrix.Scale, it draws correctly. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my area of expertise...

...but you can keep a class level Matrix to represent the current state of the "world".  You can translate, scale, and/or rotate that Matrix to manipulate the world.  Just assign that Matrix to `e.Graphics.Transform` before drawing everything.

Now, when the user clicks, you can clone that Matrix and Invert() it, allowing you to use its TransformPoints() method.  This will convert from the screen coords to the equivalent world coords.  Store the converted world coords in a List so you can reuse them in the Paint() event.

Play with this example.  Add two buttons to a blank form and wire up their click events to the respective typical method names I've got below.  Run it and click a few points on the screen.  Now hit the first button to rotate, and/or the second button to zoom in.  Now try adding a few more points by clicking some more on the form.  Hit the buttons and see what happens.  Everything should stay relative to each other (I hope):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Matrix MyMatrix = new Matrix();
    private List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point Center = new Point(this.ClientRectangle.Width / 2, this.ClientRectangle.Height / 2);
        MyMatrix.Translate(Center.X, Center.Y);
        this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Transform = MyMatrix;

        // draw the origin in the center of the form:
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(-10, 0), new Point(10, 0));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(0, -10), new Point(0, 10));

        // draw our stored points (that have already been converted to world coords)
        foreach (Point pt in Points)
        {
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(pt, new Size(1, 1));
            rc.Inflate(10, 10);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc);
        }
    }

    void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Matrix m = MyMatrix.Clone();
        m.Invert();
        Point[] pts = new Point[] {new Point(e.X, e.Y)};
        m.TransformPoints(pts);
        Points.Add(pts[0]);
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyMatrix.Rotate(10);
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyMatrix.Scale(1.1f, 1.1f);
        this.Refresh();
    }

}
```

[image: Screen to World Coords via Matrix]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this simple code can help you.  This is all done without translation or scaling of any kind.  But if you apply scaling to your graphics, it will work the same.

```
this.pictureBox1.Scale(new SizeF(2.5f, 2.5f));
```

So...

Actually I defined the side of the rectangle to 15 unit wide.

```
private int RectSideLen = 15;
```

So every time I click in the picture box I assume that I click the center of my rectangle to be drawn.  This mean that our rectangle will start at the click location minus half rectangle side.

```
int cornerOffset = RectSideLen / 2;
Point newUpLeftCorner = e.Location;
newUpLeftCorner.Offset(-cornerOffset, -cornerOffset);
```

Then I add it to a list of rectangle and refresh the picture box to redraw it with the new rectangle added.

```
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

and inside the paint event of the picture box I simply draw the precalculated rectangle.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
    {
        foreach (Rectangle r in DrawBuffer)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
        }
    }
}
```

So here is the complete sample.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int RectSideLen = 15;
    private IList<Rectangle> DrawBuffer = new List<Rectangle>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int cornerOffset = RectSideLen / 2;

        Point newUpLeftCorner = e.Location;
        newUpLeftCorner.Offset(-cornerOffset, -cornerOffset);

        DrawBuffer.Add(new Rectangle(newUpLeftCorner, new Size(RectSideLen, RectSideLen)));

        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
        {
            foreach (Rectangle r in DrawBuffer)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
However, the scaling doesn't seem to work properly. When I apply the scale, the graphics move each time a bit to the bottom-right corner (if zooming in, opposite when zooming out), so they get out of the PictureBox even before I get to zoom in some noticeable way. I actually think this was the reason for the translate I used. Any idea?